# Laravel Many to Many returns empty collection

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have two models in Laravel that I want to relate to each other. A trip can have multiple users and a user can take multiple trips. The models are set up like this.

```
class Trip extends Model {
    public function users() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'trip_user', 'user_id', 'trip_id');
    }
}

class User extends Model {
    public function trips() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Trip', 'trip_user', 'trip_id', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

The pivot table is called 'trip_user' and has ids for users and trips.

When I try to get a trips users via

```
$oTrip->users()
```

I get the belongs to many relationship

```
BelongsToMany {#267 ▼
#table: "trip_user"
#foreignPivotKey: "user_id"
#relatedPivotKey: "trip_id"
#parentKey: "id"
#relatedKey: "id"
#relationName: "users"
#pivotColumns: []
#pivotWheres: []
#pivotWhereIns: []
#pivotValues: []
+withTimestamps: false
#pivotCreatedAt: null
#pivotUpdatedAt: null
#using: null
#accessor: "pivot"
#query: Builder {#266 ▶}
#parent: Trip {#259 ▶}
#related: User {#264 ▶}
-currentlyAttached: null
}
```

When I do

```
$oTrip->users
```

I get an empty collection. I can confirm that there is indeed an entry in the table with the correct trip id and some user id.

What could be wrong?

Comment: Did you create the pivot's model?

Comment: Did I have to do that? I thought I only had to define the two models and then specify the pivot table in the relationship

Comment: @TheNumb3rMan Of curse you __don't have to__ define a model for pivot table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the Laravel docs :

> The third argument is the foreign key name of the model on which you are defining the relationship, while the fourth argument is the foreign key name of the model that you are joining to

I believe you have them switched. Try swapping trip_id with user_id in your Many-to-many relations

Comment: Thanks, this fixed it! I tried swapping the keys before but only tried this on one relationship, while you have to do this for both